# Remove a substring from the string in impala

Tags: string, hive, substring, impala

I have two columns like below:

```
a_user_id b_user_id
45610123     456
567232436    567
```

means a_user_id is some_number + b_user_id
I want to create a column c_userid where I have removed the b_user_id from a_user_id.
I am using Impala hive. sql command to do this don't work in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `regexp_extract`:

```
select
    *,
    regexp_extract(a_user_id, concat(b_user_id, '(.*)'), 1) as c_user_id
from mytable;
```

Or `regexp_replace`:

```
select 
    *, 
    regexp_replace(a_user_id, concat('^', b_user_id), '') as c_user_id 
from mytable;
```